# Using BETWEEN only if condition is met

Tags: mysql

I have the following query.

```
SELECT 
T1.guid, T1.transaction_type, T1.transaction_counter,T3.full_name, T1.transaction_date, 
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(T2.descriptions)), SUM(T2.amount)
FROM tb_transactions T1
INNER JOIN tb_transaction_item T2 ON T2.transaction_guid = T1.guid
RIGHT JOIN user T3 ON T3.guid = T1.user_guid
WHERE 
IF(T3.transactions_visibility_limit > 0, T1.transaction_date BETWEEN NOW()- INTERVAL T3.transactions_visibility_limit DAY AND NOW(), NULL)
AND T1.flag = 0 
GROUP BY T1.guid 
ORDER BY T1.transaction_timestamp DESC, T1.transaction_counter ASC 
LIMIT 200;
```

*In my `user` table, there is a column `transactions_visibility_limit` which contains the number of days the user can only view the previous transactions. If the value of `transactions_visibility_limit` is `0` then all the transactions will be visible.*

The above query works. However, I have a concern regarding this line:

```
IF(T3.transactions_visibility_limit > 0, T1.transaction_date BETWEEN NOW()- INTERVAL T3.transactions_visibility_limit DAY AND NOW(), NULL)
```

As you can see my condition `if(condition, use_beetween, otherwise_null)`

I want to ignore or stop using `BETWEEN` when the `transactions_visibility_limit` is `0` and I don't know if I am doing it the right way, I just tried my luck writing that line and it works.

Comment: It's not really clear what you are after but possibly you just need `where (date criteria or transactions_visibility_limit = 0 )`?

Comment: @Stu - editing my question, accidentally push the submit button.

Comment: @Stu - done editing the question, please feel free to ask for clarification if still not clear. Anyway, regarding your question. I simply don't want to use the `BETWEEN` if `transactions_visibility_limit = 0`.

Comment: Shouldn't the `NULL` be `TRUE`? I don't think `NULL` is resolved as a boolean.

Comment: Then again, just any value might be resolved as true I guess (which might be the reason it works). It just doesn't read quite right for me. I'd rather be explicit.

Comment: @Sam020 - well, using `TRUE` instead of `NULL` also worked.

Comment: @Sam020 - exactly, just reading the condition feels not right.

Comment: Nothing wrong with the condition. There are other ways to accomplish the same thing, but you should look into that if performance or maintenance becomes an issue.

Comment: Just one thing though, it should be `TRUE` and not `NULL`. Just run `SELECT IF(NULL, 'success', 'fail')` and see for yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When `T3.transactions_visibility_limit` is 0, your current `IF()` statement evaluates to `NULL`, which is the same as having `WHERE NULL`, which would return 0 rows. You should change `NULL` to `TRUE` or `1` as suggested by Sam020.

Personally, I think the version suggested by Stu makes the intent clearer:

```
WHERE (
    u.transactions_visibility_limit = 0 OR
    t.transaction_date BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL u.transactions_visibility_limit DAY AND NOW()
)
```

You should try to break the bad habit of using meaningless aliasing. In this query you are fortunate to have very obvious aliases: `tb_transactions t`, `tb_transaction_item ti` and `user u`.

```
SELECT 
    t.guid, t.transaction_type, t.transaction_counter, u.full_name, t.transaction_date, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(ti.descriptions)), SUM(ti.amount)
FROM tb_transactions t
INNER JOIN tb_transaction_item ti
    ON ti.transaction_guid = t.guid
RIGHT JOIN user u
    ON u.guid = t.user_guid
WHERE (
    u.transactions_visibility_limit = 0 OR
    t.transaction_date BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL u.transactions_visibility_limit DAY AND NOW()
)
    AND t.flag = 0 
GROUP BY t.guid 
ORDER BY t.transaction_timestamp DESC, t.transaction_counter ASC 
LIMIT 200;
```

You should also try to be consistent in the naming of your tables. Here you have one plural and two singular, and similarly some are prefixed and others not. You will find things are easier in the long run if you choose a convention and stick to it.

Comment: To be honest, I didn't quite understand what @Stu meant by that. Luckily, you pointed that out. Also, thank you for the suggestion, I very much appreciated it!